# Meteor and Cloud9: Node symlinkSync not working?

Tags: node.js, meteor, cloud9-ide

im trying to use c9.io to develop a Meteor app. I want to setup a symlinkSync using:

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
 var fs = require('fs');

 fs.symlinkSync('../../../../_storage', '.meteor/local/build/static/s');
```

im getting: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '.meteor/local/build/static/s'

and its true that the static/s folder doesn't exist. But on my local Meteor installation this is working just fine. If I reference a folder that already exists, then it errors: Folder already exist!

The prospects of using c9 to build Meteor apps are astounding! Lets get this working, anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree about c9 + Meteor = awesomeness. But I've run into many issues with this setup, including ones similar to the one you have here.

I think the problem is with `fs`. Since you don't really have full access to the server you are using, `fs` has very limited functionality.

I normally use c9 for certain types of development at the moment. It's not ready for everything, from what I've seen. I use it for basic stuff, and leave the big boy stuff for big boy machines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JT703 I guess we should contact c9 for more info. It doesn't seem like they are monitoring #cloud9-ide here on SO.